# Is there a way to block an iteration of a table in Lua 4.0 ? (or how to prevent the access of table content)

Tags: lua, iteration, traversal

I want to lock the access of a table content in Lua 4.01.
Unfortunately I can't upgrade to Lua 5.xx.

I was thinking to use tag method (old metatable/metamethod mechanism of Lua) but it is still possible to traverse the table without triggering tagmethods using for loop  (for ie,e in table do ...).
It's like for statement uses rawget to access the table content.

Is there a way to lock the access?
I know it would be possible using the C API but it's not really possible for the end-user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a table as un upvalue is a way to control data visibility. See [Visibility and Upvalues](https://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/manual.html) in the Lua 4.0 Reference Manual.

You maintain your data in a table local to a function. That table can’t be seen outside of that function.

An example:

```
function a()
    local t = {data = 123}

    return function()
        print(t.data)
    end 
end
```

Then:

```
b = a()
b() -- prints “123”
```

Bad practice here to just use letters for function names, but it gets the point across: `b` is just the table returned from calling `a`. But this `b`, when called, prints the data stored in `a`’s local table `t`. **There is no other way to access `t`**, so in this way you can control table access. Add more functionality (setters, getters, other logic) to `a`’s return table to control access.

**Another Example**

Showing getter and setter access:

```
function a()
    local t = {data = nil}

    local function set(data)
        t.data = data
    end

    local function get()
        return t.data
    end

    return {
        set = set,
        get = get
    }
end

b = a()
b.set("abc")
print(b.get())
b.set(123)
print(b.get())
```

This prints:

```
abc
123
```

Comment: Thanks Brianolive, I too though about that to protect accessed. 
However, unlike a table, a function and its content is frozen. Elements can't be added at runtime. Also, each time the function is called, local variables are re-initialized.
In my application, "protected" elements of the table can be modified via a "public" method of the table. Also, extra elements can be added to the table (it's a table after all) the same way, using a public method requiring authorization.
So, if a table is flexible to add/remove/modify it's elements, a function doesn't have such a flexibility.

Comment: Are you sure? Consider this from the same 4.0 Reference manual: “Note that when the upvalue is a table, only the reference to that table (which is the value of the upvalue) is frozen; the table contents can be changed at will. Using table values as upvalues is a technique for having writable but private state attached to functions.” In my example, write anonymous functions into `a`’s return table that provide add and remove calls into table `t`.

Comment: Yeah, it kind of work somehow but will be much harder to implement.
a and b different even if b uses a ref to the table t of a.
But the t used in b seems only to be an image of t at the moment b=a() is executed.
I added an arg to a modifying t.data: function a(arg) if arg then t.data=arg ...
b=a(); b() -- prints 123    b=a(222); b()  -- prints 222   c=a(); c()    -- prints 123

Comment: The idea is to only call `a` once. From there, you have one table `t` that is only accessible through the `set` and `get` methods - no other way. Yes of course if you call `a` a second or third time, those will each have its own local, private table `t`. So, call `a` only once and use the `set` and `get` and whatever else you need for your application.

Comment: yessss thanks !  I was able to tweak some code and obtain the expected result. It's a bit heavier than expected. Also I want to get rid of a command to pass "get", "set", ... so I return a table where I change the "gettable" event tagmethod to still nicely access the elements I want using  b().myElem  but myElem is still not accessible directly and not accessible via for ie,e in table do ... (which go around the implemented tagmethods).

Comment: @Laurent Glad you are finally getting the desired functionality. Vote this the correct answer then, so other users know where to find what works.

Comment: @brainolive,  I can certainly post the tiny bit of code if needed.

Comment: You can add another answer to your own question, if you think your solution would help others. I wouldn’t recommend adding code to a comment. It is hard to read that way.